# The Google Pay button doesn't appears on my phone

Tags: flutter, dart, google-pay

I´m trying to integrate google pay but the button doesn't appears, i create another project to test in this is the error i got.

in the emulator the button at least appears but in my phone not.

Edit: I just discover that in emulator with API 30 doesn't work but 31 and 33 it does.

I'm guessing that is because of my country, because in the emulator it work just fine, but when i test in my phone the button don't show up. i live in Venezuela when i tested the app with a friend in Chile it works fine on his phone.

debugging the app in my phone i got this:

```
W/Activity(27610): PerfMonitor: Slow Operation: Activity com.example.gpay/.MainActivity onDestroy took 202ms
D/AppScoutStateMachine(27610): 27610-ScoutStateMachinecreated
D/DecorView[](27610): getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
D/SurfaceView(27610): UPDATE null, mIsCastMode = false
D/SurfaceView(27610): UPDATE Surface(name=SurfaceView[com.example.gpay/com.example.gpay.MainActivity])/@0xffd4333, mIsProjectionMode = false
D/SurfaceControl(27610): nativeSetScreenProjection ===> setScreenProjection
```

The google pay button who needs the json in assets:

```
            GooglePayButton(
              paymentConfigurationAsset:
                  'default_payment_profile_google_pay.json',
              paymentItems: _paymentItems,
              type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
              onPaymentResult: print,
              loadingIndicator: const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Please share the code segment where you have used the said asset

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your resources in `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/default_payment_profile_google_pay.json
```

And in code:

```dart
paymentConfigurationAsset: 'assets/default_payment_profile_google_pay.json',
```

Comment: that's is not the problem i already added the path in the pubspec.yaml

Comment: i don't think that is a problem of assets anymore, I'm guessing that is because of my country, because in the emulator it work just fine, but when i test in my phone the button don't show up. i live in Venezuela when i tested the app with a friend in Chile it works fine on his phone.

Answer (score 0):

in `pubspec.yaml` file add:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Comment: that's is not the problem, i already added the path in the pubspec.yaml